# jQuery validator - Different error messages for same control

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-validate

In my MVC validation I am using a calendar control and all validations work fine.

```
var today = $('#TodayDateHf').val();

$('#myform').validate({

    errorPlacement: $.calendars.picker.errorPlacement,

    rules: {

        DateFrom: {
            cpDate:true,
            cpCompareDate: { notAfter: '#DateTo', 'notAfter' : today } 
        },
        DateTo: {
            cpDate:true,
            cpCompareDate: { notBefore: '#DateFrom' } 
        }     

    },

    messages: { 
        DateFrom: 'Please enter a valid date less than or equal to To date',
        DateTo: 'Please enter a valid date greater than or equal to From date'

    }

});
```

Everything works fine, but my problem is that I don't know how I can display different messages for same control.

For example, for DateFrom a rule is defined and there are two parameters in that rule, but it only displays the same error message. How can I display a different error messages based on the parameter evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
messages:{
                DateFrom:{
                    cpDate:"Message1",
                    cpCompareDate: "Message2"
                }

            }
```